# Сколько раз создается объект прототип?

Tags: javascript, функции, наследование, prototype, прототипное-наследование

Для примера есть следующий код:

```
function Test (name) {
    this.name = name;

    return this;
}
Test.prototype.setName = function (newName) {
    this.name = newName;
};
new Test();
new Test();
new Test();
```

Каждый раз при вызове new Test() создается новый объект со свойством name. Это совершенно независимые объекты. Вопрос: для каждого ли такого нового объекта создается объект прототип (в данном случае три простых объекта и для каждого прототип) или для каждого из созданных объектов он всегда один? И если он всегда один как можно это проверить?

Comment: объект один и находится в `Test.prototype` - в сами объекты добавляется ссылка на этот объект, проверить очень легко, например добавить в прототип поле и сравнить его значение у всех созданных объектов, либо просто получить прототипы созданных объектов и просто сравнить их

Comment: [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объект прототипа **один** и находится в поле *prototype* функции.

В сами объекты добавляется ссылка на этот объект.

Для проверки можно получить прототипы созданных объектов используя метод [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) и затем сравнить полученные объекты:

```js
function Test(name) {
  this.name = name;

  return this;
}
Test.prototype.setName = function(newName) {
  this.name = newName;
};
var objs = [new Test('a'), new Test('b'), new Test('c')];

//проверка и вывод, что прототипы объектов являются объектом Test.prototype
objs.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.name, Object.getPrototypeOf(el) === Test.prototype)
});

//проверка и вывод, что прототипы объектов равны между собой
var prototypes = objs.map(function(el) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(el);
});
console.log(prototypes[0] === prototypes[1]);
console.log(prototypes[1] === prototypes[2]);
console.log(prototypes[0] === prototypes[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы новым объектам автоматически ставить прототип, конструктору ставится свойство prototype.

При создании объекта через new, в его прототип **proto** записывается ссылка из prototype функции-конструктора.

Свойство prototype имеет смысл только у конструктора
Свойство с именем prototype можно указать на любом объекте, но особый смысл оно имеет, лишь если назначено функции-конструктору.

Само по себе, без вызова оператора new, оно вообще ничего не делает, его единственное назначение – указывать **proto** для новых объектов.

Значением prototype может быть только объект
Технически, в это свойство можно записать что угодно.

Однако, при работе new, свойство prototype будет использовано лишь в том случае, если это объект. Примитивное значение, такое как число или строка, будет проигнорировано.

Для произвольной функции – назовём её Person, верно следующее:

Прототип **proto** новых объектов, создаваемых через new Person, можно задавать при помощи свойства Person.prototype.
Значением Person.prototype по умолчанию является объект с единственным свойством constructor, содержащим ссылку на Person. Его можно использовать, чтобы из самого объекта получить функцию, которая его создала. Однако, JavaScript никак не поддерживает корректность этого свойства, поэтому программист может его изменить или удалить.
Современный метод Object.create(proto) можно эмулировать при помощи prototype, если хочется, чтобы он работал в IE8.

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос - Прототипе ставится один раз это легко проверить

```
var test1 = new Test();
var test2 = new Test();
console.dir(test1);
console.dir(test2);
```

Посмотрите их свойство __ proto__

https://learn.javascript.ru/new-prototype

Comment: поле `name` свое собственное у **каждого** объекта, оно к прототипу не относится

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответы

Проверить что прототип всегда один просто:

```
function test(){}
test.prototype = {
   arr: [],
   val: 1
}

var a = new test();
var b = new test();

console.log( a.val, a.arr ); // 1, []
console.log( b.val, b.arr ); // 1, []
a.arr.push( 1 );
a.__proto__.val++ 
//числа не мутабельны, при изменении происходит присваивание нового значение в объект
//поэтому если нужно поменять "общий" параметр нужно это делать через прототип  
console.log( a.val, a.arr ); // 2, [1]
console.log( b.val, b.arr ); // 2, [1]
console.log( test.prototype.val, test.ptototype.arr ); // 2, [1]
a.val++; // создась новое поле в "a"
console.log( a.val, a.arr, a.__proto__.val ); // 3, [1], 2
console.log( b.val, b.arr ); // 2, [1]
```